# Binding ComboBox with Generic List so that value of combobox item represents bound object

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying my hands on WPF. I am trying to bind a `ComboBox` with `List<MyClass>` where `MyClass` is user defined class. I want to set `SelectedValuePath` property of ComboBox so that, value of ComboBox item represents object of `MyClass`.

I tried setting `SelectedValuePath` property to `.` and `this`, but no luck. Can anybody suggest me the way to achieve it?

Example Code :

```
Class MyClass
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();

ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
cmb.DataContext = lst;
cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
// Here I want object of MyClass (which is bound to this item) itself should be assigned as value.
cmb.SelectedValuePath = "????";
```

Comment: So you try to display only one property of your own class in the combobox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cmb.SelectedItem` instead which returns an object, cast it as `MyClass` and do not set SelectedValuePath at all